# why const ref of string in the program is still valid?

Tags: string, c++11, dangling-pointer

in below program a `string cst`is created inside the block scope and store its const reference in `unique_ptr<Def> d`(`unique_ptr<Def> d` is outside block scope). as per my understanding when the block scope ends `string cst` is destroyed, so `unique_ptr<Def> d` storing reference of `string cst` should be dangling after end of block scope but its not and it correctly printing `"Hello"` string. i've check the address of `d->s` and `cst` are same so there is no copy happening so wanted to know why `d->s` retains the string value  even after`cst`  doesn't exist?
o/p : https://godbolt.org/z/zT61KoGqK

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>

using namespace std;

struct Def
{
    const string& s;
    Def(const string& v):s(v)
    {
    }
};
int main()
{
    unique_ptr<Def> d = nullptr;
    {
        string cst = "Hello";
        d.reset(new Def(cst));
        std::cout <<&d->s <<"="<< &cst<<"\n";
    }
    std::cout << "strVal : " << d->s<<  "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Correctly printing" is one possible outcome. Your program has undefined behavior. Add the compiler options `-g -fsanitize=address,undefined`

Comment: as you can see i've added godbolt compiler link https://godbolt.org/z/zT61KoGqK  even there its not complaining about any error or warning
i think they already have this flag enabled right?

Comment: No, those options are not enabled by default. Just add them and you'll see.

Comment: yes it giving error now thnks (voted +1) but still don't understand why its correctly printing.

Comment: A program that has [_undefined behavior_](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) (like this program has) can do pretty much _anything_.

Comment: You are confusing "valid" with "works for me".

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. valid  code for me means "production ready code".

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. "Works in tests but crashes during a demonstration in front of an important customer" is another.

Comment: @CY5 Anytime _undefined behavior_ is identified in your code by you, or anyone else, do not ship it - even if it seems to work. I think that's the general message we're trying to send. It will cause problems - sometimes **big** problems. Don't do it.